# C# Change x- parameter function into 1 parameter function

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

im here to ask for your help because im having a problem.

To start let me explain the current situation, 
i have an golden section algorithm which allows me to find a minima of an variable function.

For this case i created a delegate which return one value and expects one value.

```
delegate double FunctionCaller(double value);

private double GoldenSectionSearch(double PointA, double PointB,double PointC ,FunctionCaller fkt,double tol)
    {
      //find minima
      //calls function at some point
    }
```

After that im able to call my function with the help of some test functions 
like

```
private double quadrat(double x) { return x * x; }
```

So far so good, but now i want to find the minima of a multidimensional function something like

```
 private double function_2D (double x, double y){ return  ((x-20)*(x-20)) +((y-10)*(y-10)) +10;
```

as you see it isnt possible with my current algorithm to process this function. And i dont want to create for each x-dimensional function a new algorithm. So i thought i could simply split the parameters.

For example i set the "x" value of function_2D as an solid value and than let it run through the golden section function. After that i do the same with "y" and compare the difference so i can get the minima of the function.

**But for that i have to "tranform" the x-dimensional function into a 1-dimensional one with replacing the other parameters as fixed values.**

As an example i can call my function_2D with x as 5 for the goldenselection 
and the otherway

Do you have any idea how i can do this?

Thanks for your time and sorry for my language english isnt my mother tongue

Comment: I am not realy sure what you want to do. Your title says you want an one Parameter function. In you last sentences you say you want a "one-dimensional" function. To be honest I don't realy get what you are looking for? Do you want to have one function and want to call it with no matter how many paramters?

Comment: If you were to call `function_2D` with x as 5, what would you like to pass in for y?

Comment: And if you mean "I want to fix one parameter and let the other vary through the algorithm of golden section search", then just wrap the function in another delegate: `Func<double, double> function_2D_fixed = x => function_2D(x, 5);`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i like the idea with the 2nd delegate but it is still at the and a delegate which requires 2 parameters, but the problem is that i want do give my Goldensection a function with one parameter.